# Japanese characters are showing up as other symbols in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unicode, character, mojibake

I have a very simple JavaScript application which has to render some Japanese characters (specifically, half-width kana).

Here's all of them: ｦｧｨｩｪｫｬｭｮｯｱｲｳｴｵｶｷｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃﾄﾅﾆﾇﾈﾉﾊﾋﾌﾍﾎﾏﾐﾑﾒﾓﾔﾕﾖﾗﾘﾙﾚﾛﾜﾝ

However, when they are rendered to the screen they show up as other random characters as shown below.[image: Here's a screenshot.]

What's even stranger is that if I copy and paste the random rendered characters into my code editor, it turns back into Japanese!

I know that Chrome is capable of rendering Japanese characters because I can see it do so right now when I'm typing out this Question. So, I'm at a complete loss as to why this happens in my program.

Firefox doesn't seem to share this problem but Safari does.

Here's my code. I have all the characters in a string and I randomly select one to display (it's for artistic purposes).

```
let randomChar = function() {
  const halfWidthKana = "ｦｧｨｩｪｫｬｭｮｯｱｲｳｴｵｶｷｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃﾄﾅﾆﾇﾈﾉﾊﾋﾌﾍﾎﾏﾐﾑﾒﾓﾔﾕﾖﾗﾘﾙﾚﾛﾜﾝ";
  const numerals = "0123456789";

  let possible = halfWidthKana + numerals;

  return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
};
```

Then the randomly selected character is displayed inside an li tag

```
let li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(randomChar()));
```

Here is the sole HTML file which my app is formed around:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Japanese Text</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="generate.js"></script>
        <script src="Column.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="lines"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's an encoding problem. You probably need to specify the encoding in the HTML. Different browsers are probably able to make better/worse guesses as to which to use, thus the different behavior.

Comment: I have the main html page use `<meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">`. Removing it changes the random characters to different random characters

Comment: This should be sufficient. Did you try? `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: Changed it and I am getting the same results

Comment: This looks like Shift JIS to Mac Roman.

Comment: What encoding is the source code saved as? What `Content-Type` HTTP header is the Javascript file served with?

Comment: Not sure what I should specify in regards to encoding of the source. The single HTML file of my program has only the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tag. There's not Content-Type but I think they are equivalent? I updated my original question with the code for the single HTML file my app uses.

Comment: In your text editor that you use to create the file, when you do Save As…, what encoding are you choosing? (Specifics vary between editors obviously…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this on my Mac as well.

Chrome's inspector shows that the font "Songti SC" is being used. Switching to a different font fixes this.

More details are discussed at https://crbug.com/544402.

Comment: You're the man Josh! I changed font-family to sans-serif and all is working.